# How do I add a parameter to the Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, copperlicht

How do I add a paremeter to the chrome browser when starting the browser?

I try to view a local copy of a copercube 3d plug-in to a chrome browser, I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow instructions from http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-start-google-chrome-in-incognito-mode-by-default/. Instead of typing --incognito, type --allow-file-access-from-files

Another set of instructions are here: http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

Comment: Good answer.  Do you know copercube?

Comment: I am sorry I am unfamiliar with copercube.